# Why does Visual C++ give unexpected values when I try to give a number in binary notation?

Tags: binary, numbers, integer, bit-manipulation, decimal

In VC++ 9 trying such stuff:

```
int base = 0010;
```

Then in debugger I see that it's equal to 8 in decimal. I don't understand.

I thought that If I explicitly use 000 before numbers, VC++ will interpret it as a number in binary format.

0010 in binary is 2 in decimal (reading the numeral radix from right to the left as we always do).

0 -> 0

0 -> 1

10 -> 2

So why after such definition VC++ shows me that 0010 is 8 in decimal?

If 8 in decimal equals to 1000 in bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0010 is an octal literal(Since it starts with 0). Its 10 in octal which is 8 in decimal

Comment: Ahh!!! Thank you very much. I've tried 0b to use as format for bin-value, but compiler has returned an error. Does VC++ have support for bin-format? thank you

Comment: With VC++ 9 no. With a compiler that supports user defined literals (C++11 feature) yes.